# Search via push address in OllyDbg

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I have an address (eg. 00423D8C) and I would like to know how to make a search on the `main thread` like this : `PUSH 00423D8C` (and so is it is possible).

Here is an example of what I would like to get if I can do this search.

[image]

Comment: plz explain better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on disasm -> Search for -> All commands:

[image]

You put the command to search for (you can also use wildcards):

[image]

And you get a list of results:

[image]

Double-click on any result and it'll take you to that address in disasm view.

Comment: Wonderful ! Superb answer! I spent 2 hours looking for it. many thanks !!